# Getting data from World Bank in topics like economics, human rights or environment into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, data

The [World Bank](http://maps.worldbank.org/p2e/mcmap/index.html) has a lot of data on their website that is shown on maps.

Is there is a way to download this data and use it in Qgis, preferably via shapefiles?

Comment: while this is a useful answer and I'm sure the plugin is great, could you edit the question to make it more questioning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a great plugin that enable you to import the world bank data into Qgis
The first thing is install the World Bank plugin.[image: the World Bank Data plugin]

The plugin will be at the plugin menu [image: QGIS plugin menu]

Once you click it you will have a window with topics. In this window you will be able to choose topics and subtopics for a given year. Before you press "OK" you need to choose the folder that your shapefile will be saved into.
[image]

I have choose the "Agriculture, value added (% of GDP) (2014)" topic. It looks  like this: [image]
Canada is missing because it had no value.